# Why does Li Xingke bleed for no reason?

Tags: code-geass

Throughout Code Geass R2, Xingke was shown to bleed through his mouth for no apparent reason, especially in a plane or a knightmare. Does he have the same sickness as Itachi in Naruto or what?

[image]

P.S. In that picture (when the million Zeros get exiled), he says "Don't be concerned, I just have to last a little longer."

Comment: as far as I know, the details of his illness were never described in the anime

Comment: Maybe we'll find out in R3

Comment: It's been years and there was no announcement of R3. Also, like TheFlow0360 said, his sickness was never explained in detail. It was just he was gravely ill

Comment: Get out of that rock of yours. There's a trailer for R3.

Answer (score 1):

In fiction, when people cough up blood that usually means they have tuberculosis. It's a standard way to depict the illness like that.

Comment: What about Itachi?

Comment: I've not seen Naruto so I can't tell for certain, but chances are that he too has tuberculosis if he coughs up blood.